# How to use output parameter in SSIS execute sql task from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

Using a parameter, `@IsSuccess` in stored proc. How to use that @IsSuccess parameter in SSIS Execute SQL Task and take that as output from that component to another component?

[image]

Comment: look at output parameters for SSIS tasks: https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-sql-tasks-in-ssis-output-parameters-vs-result-sets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following SQL statement in the Execute SQL Task to store the stored procedure output into an SSIS variable:

```sql
EXEC mystoredprocedure ? OUTPUT
```

Then in the Execute SQL Task editor, go to the parameter mapping form and select the SSIS variable you need to store that value.

More details can be found in the following article:

- [Execute SQL Task in SSIS: Output Parameters vs Result Sets](https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-sql-tasks-in-ssis-output-parameters-vs-result-sets/)

After storing that value, you should use this variable within the precedence constraints expressions:

- [Overview of SSIS Precedence Constraints](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-ssis-precedence-constraints/)